# How to get month & day in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, date, swift3, nsdateformatter

I want to get the month & date from date as `29 NOV` in Swift. I have tried below code but this does not work me.

```
 func getMonthfromDate(str_date:String)
  {
    let dateAsString = str_date
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateAsString)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-mm"
    print("date is \(dateFormatter.string(from: date!))")

  }


Input-"19-11-2016"
Output-19:00
```

Please guide which is right method ?

Comment: Could you expand on *"does not work [for?] me"*?

Comment: It just does not give me required result

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your second formate is wrong it should be `dd-MM`, `mm` is for minute also in your question you have told that you want date and month like `29 NOV` then your formate should be `dd-MMM`.

```
let dateAsString = str_date
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateAsString) {
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM"
    print("date is \(dateFormatter.string(from: date))")
}
```

**Note :** Do not force wrap date object using `!` it will crash your application if it is `nil` batter to use optional wrapping with `if let` and `guard`.

Check this for other [date formatters](http://nsdateformatter.com/).

Comment: Thx. This helped for me in something